# Apache server shows 404 with existing files — possible user/group/ownership issue?

Tags: apache-http-server, file-permissions, ubuntu-16.04, ownership, composer

So, the instructions for creating a Drupal site with Composer state to never run Composer as `root`. So I created a new user "xylot" in the group of the same name (`xylot:xylot`), and created the site with Composer.

Now, however, Apache refuses to read the directory in question and gives me a 404 error. I use virtual host config files, and the site in question looks at `example.com.conf`. I have other sites on the same server, with different config file names, all of which are working properly.

This site is the only one with wonky user ownership rules. All directories and files within `/var/www/my-site-name` (including the directory itself), which the .conf file points Apache to, are owned by `xylot` and the `xylot` user group.

I tried changing group ownership (using `chgrp`) to the `root` group, thinking this would give Apache the ability to read my files, but that doesn't work. I'm not sure I'm on the right track, but a part of me believes so, simply because it's the only one of my sites on that server that have ownership other than `root:root`.

Is this a reasonable path for troubleshooting? Should I look at something else instead? All files are present and accounted for. I have used the domain name in question before for previous iterations of the site I'm trying to work on, and only now is it 404-ing, and only this time have I messed around with user ownership.

(I'm still very new to server maintenance and management, so please be gentle.)

**ETA:** I tried changing the directory and all subdirectories and files to `root:root` ownership, to no avail (after restarting Apache).

Comment: Hey, is that Macho Man Randy Savage I see there?

Comment: (Yes it is!) So I started fresh with another subdomain, and this time it works. Maybe there's something wrong with the original site's .conf file...